# RMarkdown pdf_output of ztable | xtable | htmlTable

Tags: r, r-markdown

I successfully generate tables using either ztable, xtable or htmlTable packages with no problems. But, I'd like to know whether these tables may be output as pdf documents. When I try to knit a pdf_output, the table is not displayed. Instead the information is displayed as several strings. I've tried changing the latex engine (using ztable) and other methods with no luck.

I've looked here:
http://www.mzan.com/article/29773068-rmarkdown-latex-table-output-difficulties.shtml

I've also looked in the vignettes, etc.

Example (RMarkdown):

````
---  
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, message = F, results = 'asis'} 
# will throw out Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
library(ztable)
data(iris)
options(ztable.type="latex") 
zt <- ztable(iris[1:5,], caption = "ztable")
zt <- addcgroup(zt,
                cgroup = c("group 1", "group 2"),
                n.cgroup = c(2,3))
print(zt)
```  

```{r, message = F }
# since it's html, will produce text only
library(htmlTable)
data(mtcars)
colnames(mtcars) <- NULL
htmlTable(mtcars[1:5,], caption = "htmlTable",
          cgroup = c("group 1", "group 2"),
          n.cgroup = c(5,6))
```
````

Comment: Are you using `results='asis'` in the header of your R markdown sections?

Comment: I did when I tried the ztable package. Let me try again and post the output message.

Comment: I did, with the following errors (used: `results = 'asis'` and later in the code: `options(ztable.type="latex")` :

`pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF from TeX source`
`Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43`

Comment: It would help to see what is contained in your table.  Do you have any characters such as `_`, `#`, or `$`?  I often forget to escape these characters with a backslash, resulting in errors like this.  It's hard to tell without a reproducible example.

Comment: also, if you have diacritics (basically, if you're not writing in English), try setting `latex_engine: xelatex` in your yaml front matter

Comment: Thank you, Benjamin & scoa. The table only has numbers and letters, nothing special.  
I've used htmlTable | ztable to add column groups and row groups to my tables.  
They export perfectly well as html, just not as pdf.  
(I also tried changing the latex engine!)
I will try to provide a simple reproducible table using the `iris` data.

Comment: added reproducible errors above

Comment: This example works for me when I add `header-includes: \usepackage{colortbl}` to the front-matter.  (for `ztable`.  I don't think `htmlTable` has an html engine)

Comment: @Benjamin You, sir, deserve a gold star!
Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding `header-includes: \usepackage{colortbl}` resolves the error for `ztable`.  I don't think `htmlTable` has a latex engine.

full code:

````
---  
output: pdf_document
header-includes: \usepackage{colortbl}
---

```{r, message = F, results = 'asis'} 
library(ztable)
data(iris)
options(ztable.type="latex") 
zt <- ztable(iris[1:5,], caption = "ztable")
zt <- addcgroup(zt,
                cgroup = c("group 1", "group 2"),
                n.cgroup = c(2,3))
print(zt)
```  

```{r, message = F }
# since it's html, will produce text only
library(htmlTable)
data(mtcars)
colnames(mtcars) <- NULL
htmlTable(mtcars[1:5,], caption = "htmlTable",
          cgroup = c("group 1", "group 2"),
          n.cgroup = c(5,6))
```
````